# Error: "Template is missing"

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am getting the error:

```
Template is missing


Missing template customers/search, application/search with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}.
```

This is happening when I'm trying to make a search bar to search through my existing customers in the database. I think it's happening because I am using a partial '_search.html.erb' but it needs to be a partial and I don't know how to fix this problem.

Here is my customers\ _search.html.erb:

```
<%= form_tag search_customers_path do %>
    <input class = "searchbar" id ="custsearch" name=query" placeholder = "find colleague" type="text">
<% end %>
```

the html it's being rendered with (in events\new.html.erb):

```
 <div class = "searchbar">
      <%= render partial: 'customers/search', :object => @customers, locals:{} %>
      </div>
```

here is my customers controller 'search' method:

```
def search
    @q = "%#{params[:query]}%"

    @customers = Customer.where("first_name LIKE ? or last_name LIKE ? ",@q,@q)

    render :layout => false
  end
```

and here is my routes file:

```
root 'pages#home'
  get '/main' => 'pages#main'
  get '/signup' => 'customers#new'
  resources :customers do
    collection do
      get 'search'
    end
  end


  get '/compose' => 'events#new'

  resources :events
```

I'm not even sure if this search will work, but this is the first hurdle to achieving it. Please help!

Thanks

Comment: The `search` action expects a `search.html.erb` template (this one is different from the partial `_search.html.erb`)

Comment: @AbM I know this, but I don't know how to fix this. I need _search.html.erb so that I can use it in another html file right?

Comment: Couldn't you just wrap the partial (_search.html.erb) in a full view (search.html.erb)? Think it'll solve your issue: You can keep the partial and keep rendering like you are now.

Comment: @azazeal yes that was one of the answers, thank you. But now I am getting an error on submit: 
Routing Error


No route matches [POST] "/customers/search"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your search action looking for `customers/search.html.erb` but you don't have any. Try create a new file in `customers` folder with name `search.html.erb` and paste your below code there:

```
<div class = "searchbar">
  <%= render partial: 'customers/search', :object => @customers, locals:{} %>
</div>
```

also remove `render :layout => false` from your `search` action. If you are sending request in html format.

Comment: ok, I am now getting the error:   
Routing Error


No route matches [POST] "/customers/search"

Comment: When you are getting this issue . On submit or something else.

Comment: this is happening on submit

Comment: Ok, so try add post 'search' in your routes instead of get 'search' under customers

Answer (score 0):

You just need to modify you controller to something like

```
  def search
    @q = "%#{params[:query]}%"

    @customers = Customer.where("first_name LIKE ? or last_name LIKE ? ",@q,@q)
    render partial: "customers/search", locals: { customers: @customers }, :layout => false
  end
```

In cutomers/_search change to

```
#customers/_search.html.erb
<%= form_tag search_customers_path, method: :get do %>
  <input class = "searchbar" id ="custsearch" name=query" placeholder = "find colleague" type="text">
```

Comment: ok, now I am getting this error when submitting a search: 
Routing Error


No route matches [POST] "/customers/search"

Comment: @SCraig This is because in `routes.rb` file you had defined `search` action as `get` not `post`.So you have two option either add a `post :get` in routes file within collection or inside `customers\ _search.html.erb` change `form_tag` to post method like `form_tag search_customers_path, method: get`.

Answer (score 0):

`@punitcse`'s answer was right:

```
def create
   # this will be looking for customers/search.html.erb
   # you have to explicitly define it:

   render partial: "search", layout: false
end
```

This *should* resolve the error.

---

Calling the partial in the view is pretty normal:

```
<%= render partial: "customers/search", object: @object %>
```

The issue looks like it's caused by your `create` action, which can be corrected to resolve it.

Comment: when you say create do you mean my customers create?